# How to mathematically represent MMA 9 Spikey?

Tags: graphics3d, version-9, polyhedra, 3d-printing

I am trying to figure out how to mathematically represent the MMA 9 Spikey in order to send to a 3D printer.

According to this [page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spikey.html), " *In particular, spikeys for version 2 and up are based on a hyperbolic dodecahedron with embellishments rather than a cumulated icosahedron."*

How might I represent these "embellishments?" An .stl file has been generated (and is [here](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:244067), for all interested) of a [rhombic hexecontahedron.](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:244067) This, however, is the farthest I have progressed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Michael Trott wrote a [blogpost](http://blog.wolfram.com/2007/05/22/making-the-mathematica-6-spikey/) on making the _Mathematica_ 6 spikey... that should serve as a good starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks for reference! I've seen it, but am really trying to get that distinctive "9" look. I will be sure to look at it again, though.

Comment: That's going to be a lot harder... it's probably Trott's secret sauce.